# How I can stop vertical scroll by mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, mouse

I am using java script/Jquery in web browser.I made a custom horizontal scroll bar which is working with mouse wheel or mouse scroll.commonly mouse scroll works with vertical bar.So it conflict with my programmed horizontal scroll bar. I dont want to remove vertical bar completely but just only to disable when we scroll our mouse.If you make sense then please suggest.

Regards,

Deepak

Comment: You need to tell us more to get help: OS, GUI library, programming language

Comment: Disable it where? What sort of thing are you making, and which programming language are you making it in? We need more details!

Comment: I am using java script/Jquery in web browser.I made a custom horizontal scroll bar which is working with mouse wheel or mouse scroll.commonly mouse scroll works with vertical bar.So it conflict with my programmed horizontal scroll bar. I dont want to remove vertical bar completely but just only to disable when we scroll our mouse.If you make sense then please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Might work

Comment: I need little more change here.It should display but it should not work only with mouse wheel.