# Disabling vertical scroll by mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How I can stop vertical scroll by mouse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625343/how-i-can-stop-vertical-scroll-by-mouse)

I am using javascript/Jquery in web browser. I made a custom horizontal scroll bar which is working with mouse wheel or mouse scroll. Commonly mouse scroll works with vertical bar. So it conflicts with my programmed horizontal scroll bar. I don't want to remove vertical bar completely but just only to disable when we scroll our mouse. If you make sense then please suggest.

Comment: "scroll our mouse" You mean the scroll wheel?

Comment: So there are horizontal and vertical scroll bars, but you want the wheel to scroll horizontally when the user is expecting it to scroll vertically? What about touch-pads and tilt-wheels that already scroll in both directions?

Comment: Did you search this on SO already, or is this not applicable to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032009/using-the-mouse-wheel-to-scroll-a-browser-window-horizontally

Comment: And this one...http://stackoverflow.com/q/2346958/446747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('selector_for_your_container')
  .bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```