# Is it possible to disable only mouse wheel scrolling to the right using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

Hello all I was wondering if its possible to disable vertical mousewheel using jQuery. I can't use CSS because I have overflow that needs to be visible

```
$("#ab").bind("mousewheel", function() { //only effect scrolling to the right??
    return false;
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate?  Copied directly from here: [Disabling vertical scroll by mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625950/disabling-vertical-scroll-by-mouse)

```
$('#ab')
  .bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or another one here: [How to do a horizontal scroll on mouse wheel scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll)

```
var mouseWheelEvt = function (event) {
  if (document.body.doScroll)
    document.body.doScroll(event.wheelDelta>0?"left":"right");
  else if ((event.wheelDelta || event.detail) > 0)
    document.body.scrollLeft -= 10;
  else
    document.body.scrollLeft += 10;

  return false;
}
document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseWheelEvt);
```

**Update**: I think this is the exact code you're looking for:

```
$('#ab').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
  // Replace with != 0 if you want to prevent left/right instead.
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX == 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/32w276xL/

Comment: no, im trying to disable the mouse wheel in only one direction(to the right) that and the script I included in my question disable the mouse wheel in all directions

Comment: Try the updated code, I think that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by this way....

HTML--

```
<div id='no_scroll'></div>
```

CSS--

```
body {
    height: 2000px;
}
#no_scroll{
    width: 50px;
    height: 1500px;
    background: blue;
}
```

jQuery--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on({
        'mousewheel': function(e) {
            if (e.target.id == 'no_scroll') return;
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }) 
});
```

The [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/7g3fw13u/)